# CSS ignore overflow: hidden

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on the navigation for **[this website](http://bigballoon.businesscatalyst.com/)** and am having trouble with the dropdown nav.

Basically, I have `overflow: hidden` applied to the container that holds the navigation items so that the rollover effect works properly (the bottom of the nav item is 'masked' off); you'll see what I mean if you roll over the nav on the website.

For **Products** there is a dropdown nav. As the site in built in Business Catalyst (CMS), I don't have control over how the navigation items are nested, but I can obviously style them / target them with JQuery.

Is there a way to make the dropdown container within `div#navigation` ignore the `overflow: hidden` rule I have applied? I have tried setting `position` to `absolute` and playing with the `z-index`, but no luck.

Any suggestions to achieve the same result are also welcome.

Comment: My work computer was crawling whilst viewing that site. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Marty I suggest you take this back to a simple solution. For example. the nav. Make it relative, remove the height, margin and overflow and add `top: -60px;`. Much simpler and you'll start to get the result you want. Also make your content positioned relative and z-index at 100.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` can't be overridden by descendent elements - they will always be clipped by the element with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Do you think that moving the contents of my subnav out of the navigation container and into a separate container is a viable solution? (via JQuery)

Comment: @Marty I haven't had a too in-depth dig, but that might work.

Answer (score 55):

Solution:
Remove `position:relative;` rule from box with `overflow:hidden;` and set it to one of her parent boxes. Then absolute boxes in the box with `overflow:hidden;` will ignore this rule.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/88fYK/5/

Comment: This does not work if position relative is needed in an element between the element with overflow and the element with position absolute. Any Idea? http://jsfiddle.net/88fYK/439/

Comment: It doesn't work properly even if you need to scroll the content of the box.

Comment: @charles In your demo the method works as expected. If really you really need box with `position:realtive;` between `overflow:hidden` and `position:absolute`- move block with `position:absolute` as child to the `<body/>` element.

Comment: @FezVrasta please describe you comment in more details or provide a demo.

Comment: @SergeyGospodarets say you need to open a dropdown inside a scrolling div of 500x500px, the dropdown is 200x800 and it will correctly go outside the boundaries, if you then scroll the content of the div, the dropdown will stay fixed in that position instead of scroll with the content.

Comment: @FezVrasta in that case use another techniques, e.g. as usual- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074114/css-ignore-overflow-hidden/9379435?noredirect=1#comment47159243_9379435

Comment: I had to set `position: static;`.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the element's position:fixed will remove the element and its children from the normal document flow allowing it to be unclipped. But you'll have to manually reposition it relative to the browser window. Not a great solution but it is a work-around.

Comment: Doesnt work for IE. Position fixed will not remove the element and move it, the element will still be clipped by the parent it was initially added to if that has overflow hidden. But if you have control over the code making the dropdown you can always add it to the end of the body instead since position fixed is always relative to browser top left corner.

Answer (score 3):

if your container is set to "overflow: hidden;" and your dropdown menu is under this container, you just need to set "position: absolute;"

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.your_dropdown_menu {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: depending on your HTML, you can just set your <ul> tag for your dropdown menu to:  position: absolute;  you don't even need to hide the overflow of the container.

Answer (score 1):

try to put position:fixed on dropdown content.

```
.dropdown-content{
   position:fixed
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For those of you who didnt find the solution to you problem in the answers already given, you can try and do what i did, wich is to give your "nav-bar" a different "ID" than the rest of the "containers"..........wich after 2h46min of trying everything.....i said why not and it worked, you never know it might be as simple as that